# Simplest way to make a car follow a route

Tags: movement, game-maker

To get the cars to follow the circuit, I mapped the circuits to several points. And using the `move_towards_point` function I make everything happen correctly.

In addition, I use two objects: **object 1 / pink square** => to be followed by the cars, **object 2 \ green square** => to reset the car collision with object 1 (**so that the collision with object 1 only happens once**).

Sometimes I have to make an adjustment in the position of object 2, because it has to be in the path between two objects 1, otherwise it will not clear the collision.

[image]

I thought there would be another solution considering that I've seen in video tutorials a platform games function (usually used on villains so they do not fall into the void).

[image]

If I am not mistaken, it is as if at any moment the object throws a particle, and if it did not reach anything until a certain moment or height (y), the object would turn around and run in the opposite direction.

I imagine there is a function similar to this to use in my case. So that you detect the circuit object and do not let the car get out of it.

It's *hard* enough to have to put up points, then move the position of each of them to the code (I had to do this, because I preferred to create only one object and keep repeating it all over the circuit, I could have created several. **Ex =>** *point 1*, *point 2*, ...).

Not wanting to plagiarize, but an example of what I want for my game, is this game:

*Game*: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moz.flracing2016.pro&hl=pt_BR

*Video of game*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knZRQZI25Fo

Comment: Usually those voids are detected with place_free, throwing particles seems tricky for this purpose.
Could you use a path for the circuit?

Comment: @Juanpa What do you mean by using a path to the circuit?

Comment: A game maker resource called "Path"

Comment: @Juanpa It worked, it turns out that I can not get each car to start in a different position (like on a starting grid) without having to mark with false the absolute option.

Comment: I got it! Just add a value to the variable **path_position**. The value of the variable is defined as a percentage of the path length. See: https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/paths/path_position.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the comment from site member Juanpa, I got a simpler way of doing what I wanted at first.

The GameMaker has a feature called **path**.

[image]

By clicking on the path, you can choose a room as the background (the room is already with the circuit drawing, so I can draw the path above the circuit drawing):

[image]

You click at any point to start the path:

[image]

After setting the starting position of the maze, the next point will be the next location of the path to be followed (see that with 3 or more points the path closes, this is because the **closed option** is selected):

[image]

Path completed:

[image]

Below is a link that will help you use some of the important features of this feature:

https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/001_advanced%20use/004_paths.html